# Receive change of eth link status notification in Java (in Linux)

Tags: java, linux, notifications, dbus

I have a Java application that needs to be aware of changes in the link status for a network interface (let's say eth0). Previously, the application used to do it by polling, but since I hate polling, I'm trying to find a way to get notified by the kernel.

One idea that I had was to use a D-Bus library, hook up and receive notifications through that. However, it appears that the dbus-java-2.7 is old (2009) and not really maintained. Does anyone know if the 2.7 version is in working state and can be used reliably? Or are there any other options to receive these notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Why hate polling? You can dedicate a thread to periodically check by using   **java.net.NetworkInterface.isUp()**

And this thread can emit network interface status notifications.

Comment: I hate polling because it is not an elegant solution. I will resort to that if there is no other way, but before I do that, I'm trying to look for other alternatives. Side-note: your answer isn't really an answer to my question, maybe it should have been a comment?